# Homological proof issue

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra

At page 421 of this [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=lqyCjUFY6WAC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), about middle page, we found:

"... for this will surely imply that $\theta_\ast \colon F_{i+2} \to G_{i+2}$ is bijective."

My question is: should the indices be $i+1$ instead of $i+2$?

Comment: Can you add some context? (What is proving? What's your notations?) Not all of us have the book anyway.

Comment: I looked up your link and I think that you are right. But, I think that your question does not provide anything.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the indices in the book are correct. The goal is to do induction over i but the index (for the groups being quotiented out) starts at i+1 so the induction step has to be a result about i+2.

Comment: The base step is $i=1$ (clear). The proof suppose that the inductive step is assuming that the result holds (there is an isomorphism) for $i$. How is that we jump to $i+2$?

Comment: The definition for F_i states the denominator of the quotient is F_i+1. So one above that, for induction, should make the denominator of F_i+1, F_i+2.

Comment: The denominator is $\gamma_{i+1}F$, why $F_{i+1}$?